# Função main(); dentro de uma função externa em um arquivo externo

Tags: c

Gostaria de saber se existe a possibilidade de incluir/chamar/voltar a função *int main(){* dentro de um **case switch(x){** em um arquivo externo, para formar um loop. Estou desenvolvendo um jogo da velha, e estou criando vários arquivos e chamando-os para o código fonte **main.c** para manter organizado. Tentarei explicar com os códigos abaixo:

Aqui eu estaria durante o jogo, mas caso o player X ganhasse, ele teria a opção para retornar ao menu de navegação.

```
//main.c
#include "functions/playerX.c"

int main(){
unsigned char game[3][3] = {'~','~','~','~','~','~','~','~','~'};

tralha(linha,coluna,game);

printf("O X seleciona a casa");
scanf("%hd", casa);

playerX(casa,game,option);

}
```

Caso o Player X digitasse **1** ele voltaria para o começo da função **int main(){** fazendo um loop vicioso, para que não houve-se repetição excessiva de código.

```
//playerX.c
void playerX(short unsigned int x){

switch(x){
case 1:
main();
break;
}
}
```

Caso não haja a possibilidade, existe algum recurso que eu possa estar usando para fazer algo semelhante?

Comment: o comando se chama `switch` apenas. Para fazer o que quer coloque o tal `switch` dentro de main, tratando o resultado retornado por `menu` que é claro a opção do usuário. É como se faz em geral. Acha que precisa de um exemplo?

Comment: Não queria por o switch dentro do main, pois o mesmo é muito extenso e acabaria poluindo o código.

Comment: mudar de lugar não significa despoluir. Mas se acha assim crie uma função como processo() e lá dentro use um loop que chama `menu()` para receber a opção e o `switch()` para tratar.   E em `main()` chame `processo()`...